# Image is directly accessible in browser from server when typed path

Tags: node.js, nginx

If i write ip address of my server and then write path of the image ,it is showing in the browser. Like (ip_address/public/uploads/file_name), we can see that image in browser. So how we can prevent that ,is it some configuration with nginx.

We are using mongodb ,and using jwt authentication.

Expected result should not display the image while actually it is showing.